Hedging benchmark issuance swaps
Suppose a corporate is issuing a fixed rate bond and swaps into floating by receiving fix on a swap (let’s say it’s a benchmark bond and thus has a significant dv01).
The bank paying fix in this swap needs to simultaneously hedge the market risk in the interbank market. Due to liquidity issues (huge dv01) it probably can’t offload via outright swaps only and hence needs to use a combination of outright swaps, liquid flies around bond maturity, bond futures etc.
Can someone shed light on how this would be approached in practice? Is there some established way (and order) to execute this?

Outright risk first. Then spreads then flies. You'd typically hedge with the most liquid reasonable product you can trade to minimise the pnl volatility and conserve as much margin/hedge costs as possible.you may have even skewed your book if this was well anticipated issuance to be able to accommodate the new issue swap. There's no real rule for this. Everything is mkt dep

What motivates corporations to issue fixed-coupon bonds and to hedge their interest rate risk, rather than simply issue floating-rate bonds?

Another consideration: if the issuer needs the IR hedges to be recognized as hedges by accountants per US GAAP FASB topic 815, then they may need to talk to accountants about doing something sub-optimal.
